# Error: (SystemJS) Cannot read property 'forRoot' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, systemjs

Hi I want to use a datepicker of ngx-bootstrap in my angular 2 project here is the code:

```
// or
import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

 @NgModule({
   imports: [BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),...]
})
export class AppModule(){}
```

SystemJS version: 0.19.40

system.js config file:

```
 'ngx-bootstrap': { format: 'cjs', main: 'bundles/ngx-bootstrap.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
```

But it give me this error:

> trajet:64 Error: (SystemJS) Cannot read property 'forRoot' of undefined, could i have your help please??

Comment: the same problem

Comment: where i add that??

Comment: s  "systemjs": "0.19.40",

Comment: in the appModul??

Comment: that will not change any thing

Comment: I tried this with both the old version in use (0.19.40) and the most recent release (0.20.18) it works correctly. Please post your full configuration.